# Impossible to conclude about limit even if we have a strong inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let's say I have a function $f:E \to E$ where $E$ is an euclidian space.
Moreover there is : $\delta > 0$ such that :

$$\forall (x,y) \in E^2, \mid ||f(x)-f(y)||-||x-y|| \mid \leq \delta$$

Then I want to show that : $\lim_{ n \to \infty} ||\frac{f(nx)}{n} || = ||x||$.
Here is what I do : 
We have $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ :

$$\mid ||f(nx)-f(0)||-||nx|| \mid \leq \delta$$

Hence we have (by multiplying the above inequality with $\frac{1}{n}$) :
$$\mid ||\frac{f(nx)}{n}-\frac{f(0)}{n}||-||x|| \mid \leq \frac{\delta}{n}$$

Now let's take the limit of the above inequality as $n \to \infty$ : 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mid ||\frac{f(nx)}{n}-\frac{f(0)}{n}||-||x|| \mid \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\delta}{n}$$
Wich is equal to : 
$$\mid ||\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(nx)}{n}||-||x|| \mid \leq 0$$
So : 
$$||\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(nx)}{n}|| = ||x||$$

But it appears that this actually false. I don't understand why can someone explain?

Thank you!

Comment: It would help if you could explain why you think it's false; do you have a counterexample?